# Is there a web site offering to browse a cloud of semantically related words?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a web site offering to browse a cloud of semantically related words?

For example to enter "coffee" and get "drink", "aroma", "stimulation", "brown", "latte", "cappuccino", "arabica", "starbucks" "milk", "cup", "liquid", "morning", "cafeteria", "caffeine", etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinkmap's [Visual Thesaurus](http://visualthesaurus.com/) seems to fit the bill as well as anything I'm aware of. It is, however, a paid service. Of course, being a thesaurus, its focus is on words related by definition, making more tangentially-related words less likely to appear (such as 'drink' and 'cream' in your example). However, it does have certain relations such as "type of" or "is similar to" which help. As an added bonus, VT uses an interactive force-directed node map to display all this. The [results for 'coffee'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57EVM.png) happen to be particularly unexciting, but I encourage you to go try out the demo version on their website.